# Avalanche upgrade cartridge for Boxxer, or tune existing?

Tags: fork, suspension, upgrades

I've got a stock Boxxer RC 2011 on my bike, and I'm not overly impressed with it's damping.  On fast small bumps it tends pack down, and on big hits it bottoms out.

As it's only got overall external compression and rebound adjusters, I can only help one scenario or the other.  My mate has the model up (R2C2), which has both the upper and lower travel adjusters for each type amongst others, and it seems to have vastly better performance.  However, having serviced both of them, it looks likes much of the difference is in facilitating the extra external adjusters (not all though).

So my question is:  Will I get vastly superior performance out of it by sending it away to have the damping cartridge custom tuned to my weight and riding style?  Or is it a bit naff by design, so bite the bullet and fork out for an Avalanche/Elka upgrade cartridge (they're custom tuned upon ordering anyway)?

Comment: Thanks! There's lots of good DH forums about (Pinkbike, Southern Downhill, etc.) - but none with the stackexchange format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the Boxxer line, but it looks like they come in both a coil and air versions. If yours is a coil one, have you considered trying a stiffer spring? It is likely the cheapest option, and should help with the bottoming out, and will quicken the rebound for the 'packing down' on small bumps. Replacing the spring is probably the cheapest option too, so it might be worth a try.

Comment: I've already replaced the spring - to a softer one.  All Boxxer springs are linear, whilst I need (everyone needs) a progressive spring rate.  Progressive rate springs are difficult to make though, so most DH fork manufacturers get the same effect through tweaking the damping system.  If I just swap out the spring to a harder one, it won't pack, but I'll lose all the small bump sensitivity.

Comment: Yeah, progressive springs would be nice. You might need the double adjustability as you originally said. Depending on the cost difference, I'd probably lean toward the Avalanche kit, since you will get that adjustability, as opposed to having the cartridge retuned and still having the single adjustment. If you eventually loose or gain weight, or want to re-tune for different events or terrains, you will be able to compensate with the Avalanche. Since you've ridden the R2C2 , have you considered selling your RC and getting the R2C2? That might be more cost effective than the Avalanche upgrade.

Comment: I have thought about it, but RC has a resale value of about half of an equivalent R2C2 - whereas the Avy is £250.